# Matlab: Why is the fill function not filling the area between two circles?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, fill

I'm trying to fill the intersecting area between two circles in Matlab. I've quite literally copied and pasted this piece of code from [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/267866-how-we-can-generate-a-union-area-of-overlapping-2-circles-3-circles-multiple-n-circles) article on Matlab Central.

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
cir = @(r,ctr) [r*cos(t)+ctr(1); r*sin(t)+ctr(2)]; % Circle Function
c1 = cir(1.0, [0; 0]);
c2 = cir(1.5, [1; 1]);
in1 = find(inpolygon(c1(1,:), c1(2,:), c2(1,:), c2(2,:))); % Circle #1 Points Inside Circle #2
in2 = find(inpolygon(c2(1,:), c2(2,:), c1(1,:), c1(2,:))); % Circle #2 Points Inside Circle #1
[fillx,ix] = sort([c1(1,in1) c2(1,in2)]); % Sort Points
filly = [c1(2,in1) (c2(2,in2))];
filly = filly(ix);
figure(1)
plot(c1(1,:), c1(2,:))
hold on
plot(c2(1,:), c2(2,:))
fill([fillx fliplr(fillx)], [filly fliplr(filly)], 'g', 'EdgeColor','none')
hold off
axis square
```

What I end up with is the following image:

[image]

However, it should appear as this image:

[image]

Why is the area not being filled as it is in the example article?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? It works fine on 2015b

Comment: I'm using R2016a

Comment: Possibly a bug, I can't find anything in the release notes for 2016a that would obviously invalidate this.

Comment: I should also note that your code indicates the circle centers have the same y coordinate, which they do when I run the code. In your figures the centers share neither x nor y.

Comment: I'm also running it on my Mac, if there is perhaps some difference with a Mac version and other versions.

Comment: That's a mistake. I was fiddling with it. It's been fixed to be identical to the Matlab Central question. Still has the same issue tho.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148343/discussion-between-jodag-and-lou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Mapping Toolbox you can use [`polybool`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polybool.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to find the intersection between to polygones, and than [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html?s_tid=doc_ta) (which dosen't require Mapping Toolbox, and is better than `fill`) to draw it. The folowing code works even without the first 2 lines that use [`poly2cw`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/poly2cw.html), but it issues some warnings. This can be solved with the `poly2cw` trasfomation:

```
[c1(1,:), c1(2,:)] = poly2cw(c1(1,:), c1(2,:)); % clock-wise transform
[c2(1,:), c2(2,:)] = poly2cw(c2(1,:), c2(2,:)); % clock-wise transform   
[xb, yb] = polybool('intersection',c1(1,:),c1(2,:),c2(1,:), c2(2,:));
plot(c1(1,:), c1(2,:))
hold on
plot(c2(1,:), c2(2,:))
patch(xb, yb, 1, 'FaceColor', 'g','EdgeColor','none')
axis equal
```

[image: circle intersection]

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lou, Grate! I was just writing you another answer about the correct use of `fill` or `patch` in without Map Toolbox. Take a look at it if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question does not work because it has some mistake in the order of the points in `fillx` and `filly`. We can see that if we set the `'EdgeColor'` to be visible, and follow the peripheral line of the patch (see below, here reduced to 20 points, for the illustration). We can clearly see that the point of the polygon to be filled are ordered in a 'zig-zag' between the circles, so it has no area at all. I have numbered the vertices of the polygon taken from each circle to demonstrate in what order the `fill` function read them.

[image]

In order to fill with color all the intersection between the circles, we need to define the 'polygon' by the points on the circles that intersect (`in1` and `in2`) in the right order. This means we want them to make a closed shape if an imaginary pencil is drawing a line between them in the same order they are given. Like this:

[image]

We start with 1 in one of the circles and continue until the numbers on that circle are ended, and then move to 1 on the other circle, and when we reach the end in the second circle we close the polygon by connecting the last point to the first one. As you can see in both figure above, the starting point and the end point of the circles are really close, so we get 2 numbers above each other.

**How can we order the points correctly?**

We start by getting `in1` and `in2` as described in the question. Let's take a look at `in1`:

```
in1 =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7    19    20
```

Those are the indices of the points from `c1` to be taken, they appear to be in order, but contains a gap. This gap is because `inpolygon` checks the points by the order in `c1`, and the starting point of `c1` is within the intersection region. So we get the first 7 points, then we are out of the intersection, and we go back in as we reach points 19 and 20. However, for our polygon, we need this points to start from the closest point to one of that places where the circle intersect and to go around the circle until we reach the second point of intersection.

To do that, we look for the 'gap' in the points order:

```
gap = find(diff(in1)>1);
```

and reorder them correctly:

```
X1 = [c1(1,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(1,in1(1:gap))];
Y1 = [c1(2,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(2,in1(1:gap))];
```

But, there may be no 'gap', as we see in `in2`:

```
in2 =
    11    12    13    14
```

So we need to wrap this within an `if` to check if the points need to be reordered:

```
if ~isempty(gap)
    X1 = [c1(1,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(1,in1(1:gap))];
    Y1 = [c1(2,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(2,in1(1:gap))];
else
    X1 = c1(1,in1);
    Y1 = c1(2,in1);
end
```

Now all we need to do it to concatenate `X1` and `X2` (for circle 2), and the same for the `Y`s, and use `patch` (which is like `fill`, but better) to draw it:

```
patch([X1 X2],[Y1 Y2],'g','EdgeColor','none')
```

[image]

With 20 points the circle is not really a circle and the intersection is partially colored, so here is the full code and the result with 200 points:

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 200);
cir = @(r,ctr) [r*cos(t)+ctr(1); r*sin(t)+ctr(2)]; % Circle Function
c1 = cir(1.0, [0; 0]);
c2 = cir(1.5, [1; 1]);
plot(c1(1,:), c1(2,:))
hold on
plot(c2(1,:), c2(2,:))
axis equal
in1 = find(inpolygon(c1(1,:), c1(2,:), c2(1,:), c2(2,:)));
in2 = find(inpolygon(c2(1,:), c2(2,:), c1(1,:), c1(2,:)));
gap = find(diff(in1)>1);
if ~isempty(gap)
    X1 = [c1(1,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(1,in1(1:gap))];
    Y1 = [c1(2,in1(gap+1:end)) c1(2,in1(1:gap))];
else
    X1 = c1(1,in1);
    Y1 = c1(2,in1);
end
gap = find(diff(in2)>1);
if ~isempty(gap)
    X2 = [c2(1,in2(gap+1:end)) c2(1,in2(1:gap))];
    Y2 = [c2(2,in2(gap+1:end)) c2(2,in2(1:gap))];
else
    X2 = c2(1,in2);
    Y2 = c2(2,in2);
end
patch([X1 X2],[Y1 Y2],'g','EdgeColor','none')
hold off
```

[image]

---

All mentioned above could be replace with the use of [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html?s_tid=doc_ta) on the vertices that intersect and give the same result:

```
x = [c1(1,in1) c2(1,in2)]; % all x's for intersecting vertices
y = [c1(2,in1) c2(2,in2)]; % all y's for intersecting vertices
k = convhull(x,y); % calculate the convex polygon
patch(x(k),y(k),'g','EdgeColor','none')
```